# casting date to datetime with 00:00:00:000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am casting several hundred million data points. I am starting with `2008-10-20 01:33:20 023` and I need to return `2008-10-20 00:00:00:000`

The way I am currently performing this is:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2008-10-20 01:33:20 023' AS DATE) AS DATETIME
```

This is performing two operations, since there are 2 CASTS.

Is there a way to do the same with just 1 operation?

Comment: You could do:  `cast(left(col, 10) as datetime)`, but I don't see a problem with your approach.

Comment: thank you but it's this also doing 2 operations?

Comment: how can i set up a test that will show me how much time each one takes?

Comment: Start with a table with sample data, perform both ways and compare. (see statistics, actual execution plans, etc)

Comment: Also, you should **[read this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)**

Comment: @GordonLinoff with your approach: conversoin of a varchar data type to a dateetime data type resulted in an out of range value

Comment: Why do you need to convert it twice? Can't the presentation tier just add the 0s at presentation time if they're really necessary?

Comment: Why not create another column of date and just assign that?  Do you need to later have a non 00 time?

Comment: @AaronBertrand there's no presentation tier, this is a data validation task from 2 sources

Comment: Ok, and the data validation task isn't smart enough to handle a DATE data type?

Comment: @Yuck Then why do you need to manually add the time part?

Comment: @Lamak because i need 2 columns from 2 datasources to equal

Comment: And you can't compare them as dates?

Comment: Then why not just do what I suggested?  A separate Date column?

Comment: im only allowed to cast one side of the data validation data sources

Comment: So one side is already 00 time and you cannot cast that to Date?

Comment: I just did a test of comparing a date to a datetime with 00 and I got a match and no indication it did an implicit cast.  I would try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, COL),0) from TABLE
```

Comment: [Oh, the shorthand, it burns](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a one time validation you may be able to avoid any set with

```
where DateTimeWithTime >= DateTimeNoTime 
  and DateTimeWithTime <  DataAdd(dd,1,DateTimeNoTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get the Date with **00:00:000**

```
DECLARE @TestDate DateTime
SET @TestDate = '2012-04-25 03:15.804'
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @TestDate, 101) AS DATETIME)
RESULT: '2012-04-25 00:00:00.000'
```